# calculating proportion of sales in powerpivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I have a powerpivot table that looks like this:

```
Product, Units_sold, Year
A         10         1990
A         5          1990
B         12         1900
C         50         1900
```

I want to create a calculated field for the contribution to overall sales of each sale, e.g. in this case divide every number by 77.

How can I do that in Powerpivot?

Comment: pnuts, the dataset is many different stores monthly sales data and so many products have multiple entries per month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula for your calculated column:

```
=[Units_Sold]/SUM([Units_sold])
```

Rename your column and choose formatting from the Home menu.